# getView() is not finding views when scrolling?

Tags: java, android

I have a list view in one of my fragments and until today I had its height set to fixed 400dp. Now I've changed it to 0dp and weighted it with other views and buttons in the layout. However, I started getting null pointers after making that change. Apparently when getView() was called for an item in the list, trying to get a resource like a textview with view.findViewById() would suddenly return null. This only happened if the scroll bar was visible and I tried to scroll down.

After doing some research I noticed that the view is set to convertView whenever getView() is fired from the scroll bar being moved. convertView is actually a textView for some reason? Why would that be getting passed as convertView? Why was this working with a fixed height and how can I solve this problem?

```
    @Override
    public View getView(LayoutInflater inflater, View convertView) {
        View view;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.interview_item, null);
            // Do some initialization
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }

//Crash on the next line with an error that text1 is a null pointer
            TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            TextView text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.job);
            TextView text3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time);
            ImageButton image = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.interview_type);

            text1.setText(this.getCandidate().getName());
            text2.setText(this.getJob().getTitle());

           //Parse the time of day from the date and format it
            SimpleDateFormat timeFmtOut = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
            text3.setText(timeFmtOut.format(this.getDate() ));

            if(this.type == interviewType.PHONE_CALL)
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.phone_interview);
            else
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.person_interview);



            return view;
        }

thanks
```

Comment: Can you give your `R.layout.interview_item`?

Answer (score 0):

It was working with fixed height because view was already initialized in if part , it was not going in else part. 
But when scroll comes, once view is created it reuses the views , so it goes to else part and in that you have initialized view = convertView, but convertView is null that time, so view is null. 
So it was getting crashed for findViewById(). 
No need to use one more view , when convertView object is already present
So change your code to following.

```
@Override
    public View getView(LayoutInflater inflater, View convertView) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.interview_item, null);
            //initialization of views goes here
            TextView text1 = (TextView) convertView .findViewById(R.id.name);
            TextView text2 = (TextView) convertView .findViewById(R.id.job);
            TextView text3 = (TextView) convertView .findViewById(R.id.time);
            ImageButton image = (ImageButton) convertView .findViewById(R.id.interview_type);
        } else {
            // do something here
        }
            //set data here
            text1.setText(this.getCandidate().getName());
            text2.setText(this.getJob().getTitle());

           //Parse the time of day from the date and format it
            SimpleDateFormat timeFmtOut = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
            text3.setText(timeFmtOut.format(this.getDate() ));

            if(this.type == interviewType.PHONE_CALL)
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.phone_interview);
            else
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.person_interview);

  return convertView;
}
```

Best practice is to use ViewHolder Pattern.